# Instanciación explícita de plantillas extern: call of overloaded is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, template

Estoy usando la librería [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) para realizar cálculos con matrices, vectores, y otras *yerbas*.

Para acelerar los tiempos de compilación, estoy intentando compilar las instanciaciones en un único archivo, y declarar todas las plantillas como `extern` en los archvos `.cpp` en los que se usan:

```
// Un archivo.cpp
#include <armadillo>

extern template class arma::SpMat< arma::uword >;
extern template class arma::SpMat< arma::sword >;
...
```

*Centralizando* todas las instanciaciones usadas en un nuevo archivo:

```
// armadillo.cpp
#include <armadillo>

template class arma::SpMat< arma::uword >;
template class arma::SpMat< arma::sword >;
...
```

Pero, al intentar compilar el archivo `armadillo.cpp`:

> In instantiation of ‘static void arma::arrayops::clean(eT*, arma::uword, eT, const typename arma::arma_not_cx::result*) [with eT = long long unsigned int; arma::uword = long long unsigned int; typename arma::arma_not_cx::result = long long unsigned int]’:
>
> required from ‘const arma::SpMat& arma::SpMat::clean(typename arma::get_pod_type::result) [with eT = long long unsigned int; typename arma::get_pod_type::result = long long unsigned int]’
>
> error: call of overloaded `abs(long long unsigned int&)` is ambiguous
> `val = (std::abs(val) <= abs_limit) ? eT(0) : val;`

La *protesta* hace referencia a la primera instanciación, `arma::uword`. El trozo de código responsable es:

```
template<typename eT>
arma_hot
inline
void
arrayops::clean(eT* mem, const uword n_elem, const eT abs_limit, const typename arma_not_cx<eT>::result* junk)
  {
  arma_ignore(junk);
  
  for(uword i=0; i<n_elem; ++i)
    {
    eT& val = mem[i];
    
    val = (std::abs(val) <= abs_limit) ? eT(0) : val;
    }
  }
```

Por supuesto, antes de intentar esta *centralización*, todo compilaba y funcionaba correctamente.

Entiendo que la *queja* hace referencia a que varias posibles *instanciaciones* de `std::abs( )` son susceptibles de compilar adecuadamente para el tipo `arma::uword`. Lo que me *descoloca* es que solo se queja **al realizar instanciación explícita**.

- ¿ Hay alguna diferencia entre instanciación explícita e instanciación *sobre-la-marcha* ?
- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Cuando dices que todo compilaba perfectamente... estabas llamando en algún momento a `arma::SpMat<arma::uword>::clean()`? Si no es así esa función no se va a compilar y, si no se compila, no puede dar errores. En cambio si fuerzas la instanciación de la plantilla obligas a que se compile toda la clase... incluso las funciones que no se usan

Comment: ¡ Muy bien visto ! ¡ *Carajo* ! Normalmente, **no usamos** esa función :-(

Comment: Pues tiene muy mal arreglo esto ... Ponlo como respuesta, con eso me conformo. No es lo que quería ... pero es lo que hay :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿ Hay alguna diferencia entre instanciación explícita e instanciación sobre-la-marcha ?

Sí, en la instanciación explícita se compila absolutamente toda la plantilla, mientras que en la instanciación *sobre la marcha* solo se compilan aquellas funciones de la plantilla que se usan de manera efectiva.

Lo que está sucediendo es que la función `arma::SpMat<arma::uword>::clean()` no tiene uso en tu código y por eso no ha saltado ningún error, pero al forzar una implementación explícita la función se compila y ahí empiezan a aparecer los problemas.

> ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?

Lo que sucede es que `std::abs` no dispone de una implementación para los tipos sin signo... algo coherente ya que en los tipos sin signo el valor absoluto coincide siempre con el valor original.

> ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Puedes crear una sobrecarga de `std::abs` para el tipo que te está dando problemas:

```
namespace std
{
  long long unsigned abs(long long unsigned value)
  { return value; }
}
```

No es la solución más elegante pero debería funcionar

Otra solución sería *templatizar* las llamadas problemáticas.

Nada te impide usar una plantilla que haga de interfaz entre tu código y la llamada a `abs`, por ejemplo:

```
template<class T>
struct StdCalls
{
  static T abs(T value)
  { return std::abs(value); }
}

template<>
struct StdCalls<long long unsigned>
{
  static long long unsigned abs(long long unsigned value)
  { return value; }
}
```

De esta forma evitas el error sin muchas complicaciones:

```
inline
void
arrayops::clean(eT* mem, const uword n_elem, const eT abs_limit, const typename arma_not_cx<eT>::result* junk)
{
  arma_ignore(junk);
  
  for(uword i=0; i<n_elem; ++i)
  {
    eT& val = mem[i];
    
    val = (StdCalls<eT>::abs(val) <= abs_limit) ? eT(0) : val;
    //     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  }
}
```

Comment: ¡¡ Cuando sea mayor quiero ser como tú !! Ya  no lo puedo probar hasta mañana :-(

Comment: @Trauma se agradece el cumplido. Mañana me cuentas si te sirve ;)